# Dotplot for 2 dna sequences python (without import)

Tags: python, plot, sequence

I would like to do a simple dotplot from 2 dna sequences without using any lib or others. I'm new in Python and I would like to learn it well

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dna1=[]

dna2=[]

length=int(input("ENTER LENGTH OF SEQUENCES :"))

while True:

```
var=input("Enter Sequence A :")

if(var!="A" and var!="T" and var!="C" and var!="G"):

   print("input other than A T C G")

else:

   dna1.append(var)

if len(dna1)==length:

    break
```

while True:

```
var1=input("Enter Sequence B :")

if(var1!="A" and var1!="T" and var1!="C" and var1!="G"):

   print("input other than A T C G")

else:

   dna2.append(var1)

if len(dna2)==length:

    break
```

for i in dna1:

```
print(" ",i,end="")
```

print()

for i,j in enumerate(dna2):

```
print(j,end="")

for k,l in enumerate(dna1):

    if j==l and i==k:

        print(" *",end=" ")

    elif j==l:

        print(" O",end=" ")

    else:

        print("   ",end="")
print()
```

OPUTPUT:

Sequecne1:ATCG

Sequence2:ACCG

[Click For Ouptput Screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpDTE.png)

"*" is used to show identical nucleotide and 
  "o" is used to show non identical nucleodtice
   and space is printed where no match occur

Comment: Thank you ! and also sorry for the delay